# How Do I do a nested for loop for up and down range?

Tags: c++, for-loop

How would I make a program that lets the user input data and then have the program count from one to the number they input and then from the number they have input to 1 and it has to be up and down but like this:

It starts off at 1, then it goes to 1, and 2  (without Spaces) on a different line, then after that line it goes 1, 2, and 3 without spaces and continues to add numbers on each line after another until it gets to the number you put into the code, and then goes back from the number you put in and goes back to one the same way as counting up but going down by using a nested FOR loop.

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int  row, col;
    char myCh;

    cout << "Please enter the number you wish to count up to: ";
    cin >> myCh;

    for(row = 1; row <= myCh; row ++)
    {
        cout << "\n";

        for(col = 1; col <= row; col ++)
        {

            cout << myCh;

        }
    }

    for(row = 1; row >= myCh; row --)
    {
        cout << "\n";

        for(col = 1; col >= row; col --)
        {

            cout << myCh;

        }


    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This becomes a triangles of fives and I want them to count up to whatever the user inputs and decrease from the user's input to 1.

Comment: OK. From 1 to 12... on a different line!? then to 123!?! and... You lost me at 12... :(

Comment: it's not 12 its 1,2 but there isn't a comma between them

Comment: Are there any spaces between the numbers?  For example, if I enter 13, the last digits are "...10111213".

Comment: @user3319381: That makes it MUCH more clear!

Comment: So, what exactly are your issues?  Nested `for` loops? Printing on one line?  Using the same index variables for more than one loop?  What have you tried (post code, not screenshot to your question)?

Comment: No there isn't spaces between them I'm trying to get the code down so it will put one number on the first line, then two numbers on the second, then three, and so on until it reaches the users inputted data and then go back till it reaches one

Comment: @user3319381: You want to print out 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456, 1235467 ... etc... on one line each!?

Comment: [i[int main()
{
 int num;
 
 
 cout << "Input a number that you want to count to: ";
 cin >> num;
 
 
  for(int x = 1; x <= num; x++)
  {
 
  
  cout << num;
  num++;
  cout << "\n";
  }



 system("Pause");
 return 0;
}[/i]

Comment: You should search StackOverflow for "c++ print pyramid triangle".  Essentially, you are printing a triangle.  It's been done and discussed already.  Learn to search first.

Comment: Wow, you can't understand.  Append the program to the question.  You code is incomprehensible as a comment as you can see.  Click on "edit" and paste the code.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is not a triangle type loop it uses two nested for loops the first one is to count up to a number that was put into the codes data, and then the second nested loop is to go back down from the number that was input by the user and back down to one

Comment: More proof of lack of research.  The different between the left triangles printing '*' and your assignment is the value is printed.  Same loop, same assignment, different output on each line.  Think.

Comment: But I'm trying to count up to the number that the user inputs and then down I put the code in the question so you can know what I was trying to do but then failed because it came out to be an infinite loop of the number imputed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the example output for N==12:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
12345678910
1234567891011
123456789101112
```

Do you notice any patterns?

One pattern I see is that there are 12 lines or iterations.  Hmmm, looks like the first or outer loop goes from 1 to 12 (inclusive).

The other pattern is not so obvious, so let's annotate.
The number in `[]` is the line number, or index in the outer `for` loop:

```
   [ 1]1
    [ 2]12
    [ 3]123
    [ 4]1234
    [ 5]12345
    [ 6]123456
    [ 7]1234567
    [ 8]12345678
    [ 9]123456789
    [10]12345678910
    [11]1234567891011
    [12]123456789101112
```

Hmmm, for each index, the numbers in each line go from 1 to the index, inclusive.

The first analysis says you need a `for` loop.  Because I don't know how to prompt the user, I'll set a fixed number for the limit.  I'm looking up a `for` loop ...

Ok, let's use some variable names like `row` and `value`:

```
const unsigned int limit = 12U;
unsigned int row;
for (row = 1; row <= limit; ++row)
{
  std::cout << "[" << row << "]" << endl;
}
```

This loop will print the "line number" within `[]`, like in the second analysis above.

Note that the `{` above indicates that there are one or more statements to be executed for each loop in the `for` statement.  The `}` indicates the end of the statements to execute in the loop.

So instead of printing the line number, you need to print each value.  Sounds like another `for` loop to me.  As your comment asks, how to make it go back to one.  Well, that's the job of the initialization in the inner `for` loop.

```
const unsigned int limit = 12U;
unsigned int row;
for (row = 1; row <= limit; ++limit)
{
  // Now, a brand new for loop to print the values.
  for (unsigned int value = ???; value <= ???; ++value)
  {
    std::cout << value;
  }
}
```

So, what can you initialize `value` to make this triangle print correctly?

What is `value` compared with to signify the end of the row?

What needs to happen after the inner `for` loop to *return the carriage* to a *new line* and *feed the lines* up by one?

Try using a debugger and see what happens.  You'll be surprised!

Comment: What does the code look like in order for that first part to happen because I also need to make it go back to one as well with another for loop